# ¿Cómo hago que esté encima de toda la vista?

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

Estoy usando la librería "SlideMenuControllerSwift" de CocoaPods.
Todo funciona bien, mi problema es que al momento de mostrar el menú no sale encima de lo que tengo en el ViewController,[image: Ejemplo que muestra mi problema]

No sé si les haya pasado antes, les agradecería que me pudieran ayudar a resolver esto.
Esta es la función que utilizo para abrir mi SideBarMenu

Appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    return true
}
```

MainController:

```
class ViewController: SlideMenuController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let Sidebar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SidebarViewController") as! SidebarViewController
    self.slideMenuController()?.leftViewController = Sidebar
    self.slideMenuController()?.addLeftGestures()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func SideBarButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.slideMenuController()?.openLeft()
}
```

}

SideBarViewController:

```
class SidebarViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MyTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var MyView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
var Content = ["Inicio", "Perfil", "Favoritos", "Terminos y condiciones", "Versión", "Cerrar sesión"]
var Icons = ["ic_home_white", "ic_account_circle_white", "ic_star_white", "ic_description_white", "ic_help_white", "ic_power_settings_new_white"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.height/2
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Content.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = MyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! SidebarTableViewCell
    myCell.imgCell.layer.cornerRadius = myCell.imgCell.frame.height/2
    myCell.titleCell.text = Content[indexPath.row]
    myCell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: Icons[indexPath.row])
    return myCell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 91/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "initSegue", sender: indexPath)
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            case 1:
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "userSegue", sender: indexPath)
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            case 2:
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            case 3:
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "termsSegue", sender: indexPath)
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            case 4:
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            case 5:
                let Login = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                self.present(Login, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("\(Content[indexPath.row]) is selected");
                break
            default: break
        }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 60.0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin saber como lo has configurado es un poco complicado, pero yo diría que no tienes el `slideMenuController` seteado como `rootViewController`...

Según la documentación tienes que inicializarlo de esta manera:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // create viewController code...

    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: mainViewController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()    

    return true
}
```

Si tienes un controlador que contiene al `slideMenuController` y sobre éste presentas otro controlador (como el que parece que contiene tu logo), el menu seguirá estando por debajo, ya que el `slideMenuController` está también detrás de ese controlador...

Si compartes más código o explicas mejor como lo has montado, te podremos ayudar mejor

Comment: Ya compartí el código que utilizo, intente agregar lo dicho en tu respuesta pero me marcaba error.

Comment: Que error te marca? Cual es el problema?

Comment: Me aparece esto "Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'"

Comment: En qué línea te da ese error? cual es el código donde tienes el problema?
He intentado reproducirlo con tu código pero a mí se me ejecuta correctamente.
Por cierto, quizá te falta asignar el controlador central: `self.slideMenuController()?.mainViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController`

Comment: Ya quedó, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes controlar el orden de las vistas usar la propiedad zPosition, por ejemplo:

view.layer.zPosition = 1;

otra forma es con la función bringSubviewToFront:

view.bringSubviewToFront(otherView).

Puedes ver mas información aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631878/how-to-set-iphone-uiview-z-index